# How to return value from function in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I want used **extension** function and I want return **String**!
I set return value from function and I write below codes, but show me **empty** value!
**My Extension function code :**

```
fun Spinner.setupListWithAdapter(list: MutableList<String>): String {
    var itemSelected = ""
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    this.adapter = adapter
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            itemSelected = list[p2]
            Log.e("categoryLog","1 : " + itemSelected)
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }
    }
    Log.e("categoryLog","2 : " +itemSelected)
    return itemSelected
}
```

When show logs in **logcat**, first show 2 then show 1 !
**Logs :**

```
2022-08-12 14:49:59.261 12074-12074/com.my.app E/categoryLog: 2 : 
2022-08-12 14:49:59.310 12074-12074/com.my.app E/categoryLog: 1 : Movies
```

Why first call **log 2** then call **log 1** ?!
I used this **func** in fragment and for this when used this in `fragment` show me **empty** value!
How can I fix it?

Comment: Use callback instead of return.

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah , How can I it? can you send to me code? Really need this help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change your extension function like below**

```
fun Spinner.setupListWithAdapter(list: MutableList<String>,callback: String -> Unit){
        var itemSelected = ""
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        this.adapter = adapter
        this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                itemSelected = list[p2]
                callback(itemSelected)
                Log.e("categoryLog","1 : " + itemSelected)
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }
        Log.e("categoryLog","2 : " +itemSelected)
       
    }
```

**Then in Activity or fragment**

```
spinner.setupListWithAdapter(list){
 // It will invoked when something is selected from spinner
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I used your code but not show me any toas message !! my codes for use this func : `saveNoteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                spinner.setupListWithAdapter(categoriesList) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "" +it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }`

Comment: I think not call `onItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Are you getting value in `Log.e("categoryLog","1 : " + itemSelected)`

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to insert the `callback(itemSelected)` line as above.

Comment: I check it and used `callback(itemSelected)` but again not call this method `onItemSelectedListener`

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk show us your code how are you doing?

Comment: show your extension function too

Comment: It's ok, sorry this problem is my side! It's ok and work me awesome, thanks dear Ammar <3

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the direct answer to your question about why the logs are not in the order you expected:

Your listener is called repeatedly **in the future** each time items are selected. The current function that creates this listener doesn't wait for any of that to happen. It sets up the listener and returns right away before any items have been selected. It wouldn't make sense for it to wait, because then your app would be frozen, waiting for this function to return because the user has to select an item before the listener is called. But if your app was frozen, then the user could never make a selection, so it would be frozen forever.

The other answers show how you might fix it, but it depends what you're trying to do. It doesn't logically make sense for this function to return a String, because you don't know how many times in the future the user is going to select an item. It could be zero times, one time, or many times.

Comment: thanks my friend. can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: Ammar Abdullah's answer is perfect. I cannot improve on that answer. That's exactly how to do it. You just need to follow their instructions carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Use typealias for callback

```
 typealias OnSelectedCategory = (value: String) -> Unit
```

Update your method with callback

```
fun Spinner.setupListWithAdapter(list: MutableList<String>,listener : OnSelectedCategory) {
    var itemSelected = ""
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    this.adapter = adapter
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            itemSelected = list[p2]
            Log.e("categoryLog","1 : " + itemSelected)
               listener.invoke(itemSelected)
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }
    }
    Log.e("categoryLog","2 : " +itemSelected)
   
}
```

call with spinner

```
spinner.setupListWithAdapter(list){ value ->
 Log.e("categoryLog","2 : " +value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I used your code but not show me any toas message !! my codes for use this func : `saveNoteBtn.setOnClickListener {                 spinner.setupListWithAdapter(categoriesList) {                     Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "" +it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  }`

Comment: I think not call `onItemSelectedListener`